# Create new lists from a list of data frames, based on specific conditions

Tags: r, list

I have a list of data frames, how do I group them into different lists based on specific conditions?

For example:

```
mylist = list(matrix(rep(0,9),nrow=3),matrix(rep(c(0,1),9),nrow=3), matrix(rep(1,9),nrow=3), matrix(rep(c(0,1),9),nrow=3, byrow=T))
```

I am trying to group these data frames into new lists, depending on their maximum rowSums and colSums. For example, these are the conditions:

```
cond = data.frame(group = c(1,2,3), maxrowsums = c(0, 3, 3), maxcolsums = c(0, 2, 3))
```

Based on these conditions, `mylist[[1]]` belongs to group 1, `mylist[[2]]` belongs to group 2, and `mylist[[3]]` and `mylist[[4]]` both belong to group 3:

```
lapply(mylist, FUN=function(x) max(rowSums(x)))
lapply(mylist, FUN=function(x) max(colSums(x)))
```

I am struggling with the part of splitting the list into subsets of lists, in particular, how do I find the index based on these conditions and subset the lists into list of lists?

Comment: Please update your post with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a true/false vector to subset your list based on whatever condition you want?

```
      mylist = list(matrix(rep(0,9),nrow=3),matrix(rep(c(0,1),9),nrow=3), matrix(rep(1,9),nrow=3), matrix(rep(c(0,1),9),nrow=3, byrow=T))

       # subset where rowsums are equal to three 
subsettedlist <- mylist[ unlist( lapply(mylist, FUN=function(x) max(rowSums(x))==3 ) ) ]
```

Comment: Both answers help so much. This can be used to loop through the data frame and create a new list: newlist = list(); for (i in 1:nrow(cond)) ...newlist[[length(newlist)+1]] = subsettedlist

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. We can put the list of data frames into a list-column.

The we get the max row/col sums of each data frame using match. Then we join it on the `cond` data frame where the `maxrowsums` are equal and the `maxcolsums` are equal.

```
library('tidyverse')

mylist %>%
  enframe(name = 'df_id', value = 'df') %>%
  mutate(
    maxrowsums = map_dbl(df, ~max(rowSums(.))),
    maxcolsums = map_dbl(df, ~max(colSums(.))),) %>%
  left_join(cond)
#> Joining, by = c("maxrowsums", "maxcolsums")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   df_id            df maxrowsums maxcolsums group
#>   <int>        <list>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 <dbl [3 x 3]>          0          0     1
#> 2     2 <dbl [3 x 6]>          3          2     2
#> 3     3 <dbl [3 x 3]>          3          3     3
#> 4     4 <dbl [3 x 6]>          3          3     3
```

If you want a base `R` solution, you just need to filter the `cond` data frame based on `maxrowsums` and `maxcolsums`.

```
lapply(mylist, FUN=function(x) {
  maxrowsums <- max(rowSums(x))
  maxcolsums <- max(colSums(x))
  cond$group[maxrowsums == cond$maxrowsums & maxcolsums == cond$maxcolsums]
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data:**

```
mylist = list(data.frame(matrix(rep(0,9),nrow=3)), data.frame(matrix(rep(c(0,1),9),nrow=3)), data.frame(matrix(rep(1,9),nrow=3)), data.frame(matrix(rep(c(0,1),9),nrow=3, byrow=T)))
```

**Condition Table:**

```
condition_table = data.frame(group = c(1,2,3), maxrowsums = c(0, 3, 3), maxcolsums = c(0, 2, 3))
```

[image]

**Make group function:**

```
make_groups <- function(mylist, condition_table) {
    tmp_list <- list()
    groupings <- list()
    for(group in 1:nrow(condition_table)) {
        max_row_cond <- condition_table[group,c('maxrowsums')]
        max_col_cond <- condition_table[group,c('maxcolsums')]
        tmp_list[group] <- list(sapply(mylist, function(x) { if(max(rowSums(x))==max_row_cond && max(colSums(x))==max_col_cond) { return(x) } }))
        groupings[group] <- list(Filter(Negate(is.null), tmp_list[[group]]))
        }
    names(groupings) <- sapply(seq(1:3), function(x){ paste('Group: ', x, collapse='', sep='')})
    return(groupings)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
make_groups(mylist, condition_table)
```

[image]